# What is the Linux command to add tftp service for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

i'm following instructions about: "Installing and setting TFTPD in Ubuntu":
it asks to: Create /etc/xinetd.d/tftp and put this entry:

```
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = /tftpboot
disable         = no
}
```

what does it mean to create....
is there any command i need to type??
and "put this entry" - it means to type in one line all the lines above?
i don't know Linux & i need your help please........

Comment: http://askubuntu.com or perhaps http://unix.stackexchange.com Both are StackExchange sites, but I think the first one fits better. StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should try superuser.

Answer (score 2):

And note this warning in the `tftpd` package description:

> Tftpd is a server which supports the Internet Trivial File Transfer Protocol
>   (RFC 783).  The TFTP server operates at the port indicated in the `tftp'
>   service description; see services(5).  The server is normally started by
>   inetd(8).
>   Tftpd is not suitable for use with the PXE bootloader; for that,
>   use atftpd or tftpd-hpa.

I don't know why it isn't suitable, but when it is labeled like that, I would suggest paying attention. :)

Answer (score 0):

That is a file. What you will do is open up a terminal and 
sudo nano /etc/xinetd.d/tftp

paste the contents, save & close. All done.